# Could Osmiridium alloy be used as armor plating? (Hypothetical, cost does not matter.)

Tags: chemistry, armors, metals

I would like to know if it is plausible. I would also like a rough estimate of the force that a 1 meter x 1 meter Osmiridium alloy beam could take before breaking.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Beams are three-dimensional objects. A 1 × 1 meter beam makes no sense. (And osmium, iridium, and osmiridium are quite brittle. A piece of armor made of osmiridium will be no better than one made of cast iron, while being at the same time very much heavier and very much harder to make.)

Comment: Hi and welcome :). As the bot wisely mentioned, we lack some details to know what is your intentions, regarding this armor, so it's hard to answer without being very theorical and/or making possibly assumptions. Armor plating are made for a specific job, and designed for different purposes. What kind of foes your armored building/vehicle/guy/parrot will face, for instance? Are we dealing with low technology weapons/hazards, or higher ones?

Comment: You *need* a thickness before we can estimate anything for you sorry.

Answer (score 3):

**Osmium is brittle.**

[image: osmium]

Here is a screenshot comparing metallic osmium to stainless steel.  I am making my comparison armor out of stainless because I want it to stay shiny.  You will see that despite its phenomenal hardness and great density osmium is less fracture resistant than steel.

There are different ways to apply force.  Consider compression and tension.  You can park a car on a concrete cinder block.  But if you hung a car from a cinder block you would pull it apart.  Different types of material strength.  Osmium is good for compression and tension but it is brittle.  It is like diamond in that respect: super hard but will fracture if struck.  Brittleness aka fracture toughness (or sometimes just "toughness") could be important for armor.

If your armor is against kinetic weapons osmium is not ideal.  If your armor is against sandblasters, or atmospheric re-entry, or beam weapons trying to melt you, or repeated rubbing on a phonograph disc, osmium might be what you want.

Comment: I was going to give this answer if I hadn't found it already here.  All the platinum group metals are brittle.  Maybe some additional alloying agent, but you'll give up significant density by adding much of anything else.